# How do i get the facebook username of a given PFUser?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, parse-platform

PFUser *aUser = [PFUser currentUser]; //may not be the current user NSLog("username %@", [aUser username]); //This is ok if its not a FB user. otherwhise it gives me a token. I know there is a [PFUser isLinkedWithUser:aUser] that returns is the CURRENT LOGGED USER is linked, but aUser may not be the the current in this device.

This works ok for the currentUser:

```
+ (void)getUsernameWithCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString *username))handler {
if([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:[PFUser currentUser]]){ //<- 
    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSDictionary *userData = (NSDictionary *)result;
        NSString *name = userData[@"name"];
        handler(name);
    }}];
} else {
    handler([[PFUser currentUser] username]);
}
```

}

But i want something like this

```
+(void)getUsernameWithUser:(PFUser *)user andCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSString     *username))handler {
if([PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]){ //<- THIS ALWAYS RETURN FALSE
   //return the real facebook username
   } else {
         handler([user username]);
     }
 }
```

In the doc says: isLinkedWithUser:

Whether the user has their account linked to Facebook.

(BOOL)isLinkedWithUser:(PFUser *)user Parameters user User to check for a facebook link. The user must be logged in on this device.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have users who aren't the current user, the authData isn't sent. You have two options:

1. Each user can store their Facebook username (and any other data you want publicly accessible) in the User table.
2. Create a cloud code function which uses the master key to retrieve the authData and queries for the Facebook username.

For option two, your cloud code should do something similar to the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("facebookAlias", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  new Parse.Query(Parse.User).get(request.params.user_id).then(function(user) {
    var authData = user.get("authData");

    // Quit early for users who aren't linked with Facebook
    if (authData === undefined || authData.facebook === undefined) {
      response.success(null);
       return;
    }

    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://graph.facebook.com/me",
      params: {
        access_token: authData.facebook.access_token,
        fields: "username",
      }
    });

  }).then(function(json) {
     response.success(JSON.parse(json)["username"]);

  // Promises will let you bubble up any error, similar to a catch statement
  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
  });
});
```

Disclaimer: the above code is roughly from a personal project but enough has been tweaked that I don't warrant against syntax errors.